# Avoid files in use when automatically deleting files in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make something that cleans files, basically deletes everything inside the folder. I face an issue how ever, when trying to clean %temp%, I run in to the issue that some files are in use inside %temp% file. How can I avoid these? Or just make it so it creates an exception for files that are in use. Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim directoryName As String = "C:\Windows\Temp"
        For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            File.Delete(deleteFile)
        Next
        MsgBox("Temp Files Cleaned", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
```

I also need it to **permanently** delete files, not just send to recycle bin.

Comment: You need to use a Try - Catch block to catch and handle the IOException that occurs when you try to delete a file that is in use.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim directoryName As String = "C:\Windows\Temp"
    For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        Try
            File.Delete(deleteFile)
        Catch ex As IOException
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next
    MsgBox("Temp Files Cleaned", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
```

The above code will swallow the "In use" error and go on with the deletion process.

Answer (score 0):

As honeyboy says some like the following:

```
Try

    File.Delete(deleteFile)

Catch fe As System.IO.IOException
'do something

Finally

End Try
```

Comment: use  'Catch ex As Exception' to find the exact exception type

Comment: It seemed to have worked Eric. Thanks for the piece of information, and Honeyboy!